# Teiid QueryParser not parsing SELECT TOP number|percent column_name(s)

Tags: teiid

When I try to parse a Select query with TOP clause , for e.g.  SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Customers

Getting the below error message:
java.lang.Exception: org.teiid.api.exception.query.QueryParserException: TEIID31100 Parsing error: Encountered "SELECT TOP [ * ]10[ * ] * FROM" at line 1, column 12.
Was expecting:  | "and" | "as" | "between" | "except" | "fetch" | "from" | "in" | "intersect" |

It works fine with LIMIT clause but not with TOP clause.
Databases such as SQL Server support the TOP clause to retrieve a limited number of rows. 
Is TOP clause not supported in Teiid Query Parser ?

Answer (score 0):

Teiid supports similar functionality using the LIMIT shown in [1]. I believe Teiid does not support TOP as it is not ANSI standard.

[1]http://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/master/content/reference/r_limit-clause.html